# mysql access is deined if php file is on the server

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

When I keep my `php` in local host and try to access database from my website's domain, every thing works fine. But when I upload my `php` file to the server and then when I try to open the `php` file I get an access denied error.

Warning: `mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user`

How can I solve this error.

And I have one more question. Can I access a database stored in one domain from `php` file stored in another domain even if both domains are shared on same hosting?

Thanks

Comment: If the above comment isn't specific enough, it's more than likely your password.

Comment: Username and password are correct. I am using same username and password to create and update my database

Comment: If you are on a shared server the one on the net usually requires the host server username prefixing the db name separated with an underscore: hostservername_dbname

Comment: Yes my database is created like that only. And my user name also have a prefix pf host server

Answer (score 0):

Answer first question:
did you use the right username and password ? i think your username and password are different on your local computer.

Second question:
Yes it is possible if you use the right username and password.

Comment: Username and password are correct because I can access the database. But when I upload exact same file I get access denied. I am using same username and password to edit my mysql database remotely and it is working very well

Comment: is your database address correct ? something like "localhost"

Comment: My database address is correct. Right now I am performing sql query on heidisql using same username passwaord.